# Converting this xml file to my object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

This is similar to questions like [What is the easiest way to convert this XML document to my object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912483/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-this-xml-document-to-my-object), but i think has some additional complexity.

I would like to get the below objects out of this xml. However, because things I need for my Bean class are in similarly named sub elements rather than attributes and since parts and collections are a bit of a mess. I'm not entirely sure how to approach this.

XML, which I have in an XDocument

```
<bean class="com.nathan.etc.etc">
  <property name="documentName" value="\\myfilepath" />
  <property name="containerNames">
    <list>
      <value>One</value>
      <value>Two</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="partNames">
    <list>
        <list>
            <value>First Part of One</value>
            <value>Second Part of One</value>
        </list>
        <list>
            <value>First Part of Two</value>
            <value>Second Part of Two</value>
        </list>
    </list>
  </property>   
</bean>
```

C# code

```
class Bean {

    public string FilePath {get; set;}   //eg "\\myfilepath"

    public List<Container> Containers {get; set;}

}

class Container {

    public string Name {get; set;}  //eg "One"

    public List<Part > Parts {get; set;}

}

class Part {

    public string Name {get; set;}   //eg "First Part of One"

}
```

Comment: I'm assuming there are fancy serializing tricks like in the linked question. My original plan was to dig around using XDocument for what I need, but that is tricky and produces brittle confusing code.

Comment: Probably will be easier to read your XML and manually build your object structure

Comment: You mean use somthing like xml.linq as in: ...  var properties = beanObject.Elements("property").ToList(); DocumentPath = properties.Where(item => item.Attribute("name").Value == "documentName").First().Attribute("value").Value;   ... and dig it out manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing for a `XmlDocument`, but you can easily adapt for a `XDocument`:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
// ... load it

var bean = new Bean{ Containers = new List<Container>() };
bean.FilePath = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/bean/property[@name='documentName']")
                      .GetAttribute("value");
int index = 1;
foreach(XmlElement xmlContainer in xmlDoc.SelectNodes(
           "/bean/property[@name='containerNames']/list/value"))
{
    var container = new Container
    { 
        Name  = xmlContainer.InnerText,
        Parts = new List<Part>()
    };

    foreach(XmlElement xmlPart in xmlDoc.SelectNodes(String.Format(
           "/bean/property[@name='partNames']/list/list[{0}]/value", index)))
    {
        var part = new Part{ Name = xmlPart.InnerText };
        container.Parts.Add(part);
    }

    bean.Containers.Add(container);
    index++;
}
```