# How to add childNodes to a List of a specific datatype

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I already asked a lot of questions these past days for c# and xml but I think this should be the final one haha.

I have this code where I filter the datasets of an xml and want to add all childnodes to a list. This is how my code looks:

```
Auto[] carArray = { };
List<Auto> carLists = sHelper.showData(typeof(List<Auto>), "car.xml") as List<Auto>;
List<Auto> temp = new List<Auto>();

foreach (var item in carLists)
{
    // Enter the id of the vehicle that you want to add to this category
    Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie die Id von dem Fahrzeug ein, welches Sie dieser Kategorie hinzufügen möchten?");

    while (status)
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

        xDoc.Load("car.xml");
        var tgt = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("ArrayOfAuto");
        var setToDelete = tgt.SelectSingleNode("Auto[@id=" + Console.ReadLine() + "]");

        if (item.id.Equals(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())))
        {
            temp.Add(tgt.ChildNodes)
        }
        // Would you like to add another car? If so, press 1, otherwise press 2 to return to the main menu
        Console.WriteLine("Möchten Sie noch ein Auto Hinzufügen? Falls ja drücken Sie auf die 1 andernfalls auf die 2 um wieder ins Hauptmenü zu gelangen");

        switch (Console.ReadLine())
        {
            case "1":
                break;
```

I want to save the child nodes to temp which is a List of the type Auto and this is where my problem starts, I could not convert tgt.ChildNodes to Auto. Could someone maybe help me one final time out

Comment: Your code is trying to “Add” something to the `temp` list that is NOT an `Auto` type object. Specifically, `tgt.ChildNodes` is NOT an `Auto` object. This is what the error is saying.

Comment: thought so, is there any way to convert tgt to Auto?

Comment: What is `tgt`’s type? It is hard to tell. If `tgt.ChildNodes` is a `List<Auto>` of `Auto` objects, then simply set `temp = tgt.ChildNodes.`

Comment: Tgt gets the childnodes of Auto filtered with the id. But the thing is I have to loop through foreach and add each childnode which has the right attribute (id)

Comment: You must convert the attributes and values contained in the node to an `Auto` yourself or use a serializer [What is the easiest way to convert this XML document to my object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14912483/880990)

Comment: Then loop through the list and get the values you want. When you find one that matches then add That `Auto` to the list. Without seeing what an `Auto` object is, or whatever type `tgt` is… it is difficult to offer help. From what I can decipher it looks like an `Auto` object has a property `ChildNodes` that is a `List<Auto>` objects… this is very odd IMHO.